# Manual http request to Amazon SQS is denied

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to send a [manual http request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html#POSTRequests) according to amazon documentation, but always get Access denied response. However, if I use amazon sqs client everything works. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
DefaultRequest request = new DefaultRequest("AmazonSQS");
request.setResourcePath("myQueue");
request.setEndpoint(new URI("https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"));
request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);
request.addParameter("Action", "SendMessage");
request.addParameter("Version", "2012-11-05");
request.addParameter("MessageBody", "Default String");

AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
signer.setServiceName("AmazonSQS");
signer.setRegionName("eu-west-1");
signer.sign(request, new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials());

CloseableHttpClient aDefault = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myQueue");
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(URLEncoder.encode("Action=SendMessage" +
    "&MessageBody=Default String" +
    "&Version=2012-11-05" +
    "&Expires=2011-10-15T12:00:00Z" +
    "&" + request.getHeaders().get("Authorization"), "UTF-8")));
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
aDefault.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are not using the official [Java SDK for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-java/)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to use non blocking requests, which official sdk doesn't suppor afaik, but even if it doesn't work out, I want to understand what I'm doing wrong in sending manual requests

Comment: To check whether the queue is setup correctly, can you use `send-message` successfully from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? Have you put appropriate permissions on the queue for the credentials you are using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, if I use official sdk, I can successfully publish messages into that queue. The problem is only when I create and send manual requests

Comment: there seems to be an async client in the sdk: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSAsyncClient.html

Comment: Also, you maybe able to borrow from sdk source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/aws-java-sdk-sqs/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs

Comment: Async client uses executor service, which is not non blocking, that's why I need to manually create http request and use non blocking client

Comment: setServiceName should probably be just `sqs`, why are you setting that and region explicitly anyway, I thought those were inferred form the endpoint url automatically.

Comment: I debugged the values from official sdk. Region can be omitted, but without service name I get NPE

Comment: At least one problem is that you're doing `URLEncoder.encode()` on the entire body.  The correct way to build a form post is to encode the keys and values, only, concatenating the encoded values together with the `&` and `=`.  Encoding `&` is guaranteed to do the wrong thing, since it becomes `%26` or possibly `&amp;` and encoding `=` may also result in `%3D`.